# Convert selected column values to another row using select with the same id

Tags: php, mysql, select, row

I am making a simple time in and time out system.. i have 3 pairs of in and outs. p_id(person_id)

TableA

```
p_id  time_id      status            timestamp
1         1           in        2013-12-18 15:44:09
2         2           in        2013-12-18 16:23:19
1         3           out       2013-12-18 18:31:11
1         4           in        2013-12-18 18:50:11
3         5           out       2013-12-18 19:20:16
1         6           out       2013-12-18 19:50:11
2         7           out       2013-12-18 19:51:19
1         8           in        2013-12-19 07:51:19
1         9           out       2013-12-19 12:00:19
1         10          in        2013-12-19 01:00:19
1         11          out       2013-12-19 05:30:19
1         12          in        2013-12-19 07:51:19
1         13          out       2013-12-19 11:00:19
```

How can I select the table into Table Result (one row for the same date and the in and out pairs up to the right is ascending according to time_id)? please check this simple example, maybe you have an idea. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dd1f/8

```
p_id status     timestamp        status     timestamp       status     timestamp          status      timestamp          status     timestamp       status      timestamp
1    in   2013-12-18 15:44:09   out   2013-12-18 18:31:11  in    2013-12-18 18:50:11    out     2013-12-18 19:50:11
2    in   2013-12-18 16:23:19   out   2013-12-18 19:51:19  
3                               out   2013-12-18 19:20:16
1    in   2013-12-19 07:51:19   out   2013-12-19 12:00:19  in    2013-12-19 01:00:19    out     2013-12-19 05:30:19     in    2013-12-19 07:51:19   out       2013-12-19 11:00:19
```

Comment: I'm sorry.. hehe.. I made a few edits already.. thankyou in advance. :)

Comment: This seems to be [a direct repeat of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20653309/472495) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20672754/472495). In general it is better to make edits to existing questions, rather than duplicating them, so as to avoid creating duplicate effort from readers.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you'll get, using pure SQL is something like this (untested but you get the idea):

```
SELECT p_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(status, " ", timestamp)) inout
FROM TableA
GROUP BY p_id, DATE(timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly how to solve, but I know that what you are looking for is a pivot: 
read more about in: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Comment: I think it's only a left join.. but i don't know what exactly to do. :) anyway thanks for the advice.

Comment: the problem is that there can be infinite in/out records for a particular day/p_id combo and thus the query needs to be recursive. As far as I'm aware, MySQL won't do that.

Comment: you can't use left join because colluns on resultset are dynamics

Comment: are there any need to change the structure of my table? please help.

Comment: they gave me this answer yesterday on my part1 question. please take a look..  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dd1f/8       My question now is that I wanted to do 3 pairs of in/out record per person on the same date (another row for another date)