# Complicated select query for a simple in/out record

Tags: php, mysql, select, row

I am making a simple time in and time out system. I have 3 pairs of in/out.

```
emp_id    td_id    status     timestamp          remarks
  35        1        in   2013-12-19 10:15:09     late
  35        2        out  2013-12-19 12:00:23     example
  35        3        in   2013-12-19 13:00:23
  35        4        out  2013-12-19 16:01:47
  35        5        in   2013-12-19 18:01:17
  35        6        out  2013-12-19 22:01:07
  35        7        in   2013-12-20 10:00:12
```

Here's my query:

```
 SELECT a1.emp_id, a1.status, a1.timestamp, a2.status, a2.timestamp, a3.status, a3.timestamp, a4.status, a4.timestamp,  a5.status, a5.timestamp, a6.status, a6.timestamp
 FROM overallrec a1
 LEFT JOIN overallrec a2 ON a2.emp_id = a1.emp_id
 AND a2.status =  'out'
 LEFT JOIN overallrec a3 ON a3.emp_id = a1.emp_id
 AND a3.status =  'in'
 AND a3.timestamp <> a1.timestamp
 LEFT JOIN overallrec a4 ON a4.emp_id = a1.emp_id
 AND a4.status =  'out'
 AND a4.timestamp <> a2.timestamp
 LEFT JOIN overallrec a5 ON a5.emp_id = a1.emp_id
 AND a5.status =  'in'
 AND a5.timestamp <> a3.timestamp
 LEFT JOIN overallrec a6 ON a6.emp_id = a1.emp_id
 AND a6.status =  'in'
 AND a6.timestamp <> a4.timestamp
 WHERE a1.status =  'in'
```

Here's my result:

```
emp_id    status     timestamp      status     timestamp       status     timestamp      status     timestamp       status     timestamp       status     timestamp
  35       in   2013-12-19 10:15:09  out  2013-12-19 12:00:23   in   2013-12-19 13:00:23   out  2013-12-19 16:01:47   in   2013-12-19 18:01:17   out  2013-12-19 22:01:07
  35       in   2013-12-20 10:00:12  out  2013-12-19 12:00:23   in   2013-12-19 13:00:23   out  2013-12-19 16:01:47   in   2013-12-19 18:01:17   out  2013-12-19 22:01:07
```

Notice the first 'in' timestamp value row 2 is another date, but the next status timestamp and soon are repeating from the previous date. I want it to display null when still empty and not to copy the value on previous date. In other words, it should generate another row on day change.

Additional Remarks: when I add remarks at every input, it will be concatenated in the table result. I wanted it to be like this:

```
 emp_id    status     timestamp      status     timestamp       status     timestamp        status     timestamp       status     timestamp       status     timestamp      remarks
  35       in   2013-12-19 10:15:09  out  2013-12-19 12:00:23   in   2013-12-19 13:00:23   out  2013-12-19 16:01:47   in   2013-12-19 18:01:17   out  2013-12-19 22:01:07   "Late, Example"
  35       in   2013-12-20 10:00:12  null         null            null          null         null          null         null         null            null          null    "Straight time"
```

What should i do on my query? Or if not with the query, what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed answer, i forgot to order by timestamp1,here's the final version that will take care of multiple employees :)
[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e218/6/0)

```
SELECT T1.emp_id,T1.status1 as status1,T1.timestamp1 as timestamp1,
                 T1.status2 as status2,T1.timestamp2 as timestamp2,
                 T2.status1 as status3,T2.timestamp1 as timestamp3,
                 T2.status2 as status4,T2.timestamp2 as timestamp4,
                 T3.status1 as status5,T3.timestamp1 as timestamp5,
                 T3.status2 as status6,T3.timestamp2 as timestamp6
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT IF(((@row+1)=4) OR (@prevEmpId<>a1.emp_id),@row:=1,@row:=@row+1) as row,a1.emp_id,a1.status as status1,a1.timestamp as timestamp1,
             'out' as status2,
              @prevEmpId:=a1.emp_id,
       (SELECT min(timestamp) as timestamp2
        FROM overallrec a2
        WHERE a2.timestamp > a1.timestamp
          AND a2.emp_id = a1.emp_id
          AND a2.status = 'out') as timestamp2
        FROM overallrec a1,(SELECT @row:=0,@prevEmpId:=0)r
        WHERE a1.status = 'in'
     ORDER BY a1.emp_id,timestamp1
    )T100
    WHERE row=1
  )T1
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT IF(((@row+1)=4) OR (@prevEmpId<>a1.emp_id),@row:=1,@row:=@row+1) as row,a1.emp_id,a1.status as status1,a1.timestamp as timestamp1,
             'out' as status2,
              @prevEmpId:=a1.emp_id,
       (SELECT min(timestamp) as timestamp2
        FROM overallrec a2
        WHERE a2.timestamp > a1.timestamp
          AND a2.emp_id = a1.emp_id
          AND a2.status = 'out') as timestamp2
        FROM overallrec a1,(SELECT @row:=0,@prevEmpId:=0)r
        WHERE a1.status = 'in'
     ORDER BY a1.emp_id,timestamp1
   )T200 
   WHERE row=2
 )T2
ON T1.emp_id = T2.emp_id AND DATE_FORMAT(T2.timestamp1,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(T1.timestamp1,'%Y-%m-%d')
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT * FROM
     (SELECT IF(((@row+1)=4) OR (@prevEmpId<>a1.emp_id),@row:=1,@row:=@row+1) as row,a1.emp_id,a1.status as status1,a1.timestamp as timestamp1,
             'out' as status2,
              @prevEmpId:=a1.emp_id,
       (SELECT min(timestamp) as timestamp2
        FROM overallrec a2
        WHERE a2.timestamp > a1.timestamp
          AND a2.emp_id = a1.emp_id
          AND a2.status = 'out') as timestamp2
        FROM overallrec a1,(SELECT @row:=0,@prevEmpId:=0)r
        WHERE a1.status = 'in'
     ORDER BY a1.emp_id,timestamp1
     )T300 
  WHERE row=3
 )T3
ON T1.emp_id = T3.emp_id AND DATE_FORMAT(T3.timestamp1,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(T1.timestamp1,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

However this query won't work if employee clocks in one day and then then clocks out the next day because it's making use of the same day check in order to LEFT JOIN

OP asked for a view, but View in mySQL doesn't allow variables so I tried to write a different query (not using variables) such as this one ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afe72/1/0))

```
SELECT T4.emp_id,T4.status1,T4.timestamp1,T4.status2,T4.timestamp2,
   T4.status3,T4.timestamp3,T4.status4,T4.timestamp4,T4.status5,T4.timestamp5,
   'out' as status6,
   (SELECT min(timestamp)
    FROM overallrec a
    WHERE a.timestamp > T4.timestamp5
      AND a.emp_id = T4.emp_id
      AND a.status = 'out') as timestamp6
  FROM
  (SELECT T3.emp_id,T3.status1,T3.timestamp1,T3.status2,T3.timestamp2,
   T3.status3,T3.timestamp3,T3.status4,T3.timestamp4,
   'in' as status5,
  (SELECT min(timestamp)
    FROM overallrec a
    WHERE a.timestamp > T3.timestamp4
      AND a.emp_id = T3.emp_id
      AND a.status = 'in') as timestamp5
  FROM
  (SELECT T2.emp_id,T2.status1,T2.timestamp1,T2.status2,T2.timestamp2,
   T2.status3,T2.timestamp3,
   'out' as status4,
  (SELECT min(timestamp)
    FROM overallrec a
    WHERE a.timestamp > T2.timestamp3
      AND a.emp_id = T2.emp_id
      AND a.status = 'out') as timestamp4
  FROM
  (SELECT T1.emp_id,T1.status1,T1.timestamp1,T1.status2,T1.timestamp2,
        'in' as status3,
    (SELECT min(timestamp)
    FROM overallrec a
    WHERE a.timestamp > T1.timestamp2
      AND a.emp_id = T1.emp_id
      AND a.status = 'in') as timestamp3
  FROM
   (SELECT a1.emp_id,a1.status as status1,a1.timestamp as timestamp1,
         'out' as status2,
   (SELECT min(timestamp) as timestamp2
    FROM overallrec a2
    WHERE a2.timestamp > a1.timestamp
      AND a2.emp_id = a1.emp_id
      AND a2.status = 'out') as timestamp2
    FROM overallrec a1
    WHERE a1.status = 'in'
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM overallrec e
                                   WHERE e.timestamp < a1.timestamp
                                     AND e.emp_id = a1.emp_id
                                    AND DATE_FORMAT(e.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') = 
                                        DATE_FORMAT(a1.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d'))
   )T1
   )T2
   )T3
   )T4;
```

Unfortunately, mySQL views don't allow subqueries (Subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.)
but what mySQL allow is to create Views on top of views so here is the views created
([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67f10/1/0))

```
CREATE VIEW T100 AS
SELECT a1.emp_id,a1.status as status1,a1.timestamp as timestamp1,
         'out' as status2,
   (SELECT min(timestamp) as timestamp2
    FROM overallrec a2
    WHERE a2.timestamp > a1.timestamp
      AND a2.emp_id = a1.emp_id
      AND a2.status = 'out') as timestamp2
    FROM overallrec a1
    WHERE a1.status = 'in'
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM overallrec e
                                   WHERE e.timestamp < a1.timestamp
                                     AND e.emp_id = a1.emp_id
                                    AND DATE_FORMAT(e.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') = 
                                        DATE_FORMAT(a1.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d'));

CREATE VIEW T200 AS
SELECT T1.emp_id,T1.status1,T1.timestamp1,T1.status2,T1.timestamp2,
        'in' as status3,
    (SELECT min(timestamp)
    FROM overallrec a
    WHERE a.timestamp > T1.timestamp2
      AND a.emp_id = T1.emp_id
      AND a.status = 'in') as timestamp3
  FROM T100 AS T1;

CREATE VIEW T300 AS
SELECT T2.emp_id,T2.status1,T2.timestamp1,T2.status2,T2.timestamp2,
   T2.status3,T2.timestamp3,
   'out' as status4,
  (SELECT min(timestamp)
    FROM overallrec a
    WHERE a.timestamp > T2.timestamp3
      AND a.emp_id = T2.emp_id
      AND a.status = 'out') as timestamp4
  FROM T200 AS T2;

CREATE VIEW T400 AS
SELECT T3.emp_id,T3.status1,T3.timestamp1,T3.status2,T3.timestamp2,
   T3.status3,T3.timestamp3,T3.status4,T3.timestamp4,
   'in' as status5,
  (SELECT min(timestamp)
    FROM overallrec a
    WHERE a.timestamp > T3.timestamp4
      AND a.emp_id = T3.emp_id
      AND a.status = 'in') as timestamp5
  FROM T300 AS T3; 

CREATE VIEW myFinalView AS
SELECT T4.emp_id,T4.status1,T4.timestamp1,T4.status2,T4.timestamp2,
   T4.status3,T4.timestamp3,T4.status4,T4.timestamp4,T4.status5,T4.timestamp5,
   'out' as status6,
  (SELECT min(timestamp)
    FROM overallrec a
    WHERE a.timestamp > T4.timestamp5
      AND a.emp_id = T4.emp_id
      AND a.status = 'out') as timestamp6
  FROM T400 AS T4;
```

so there we have it a VIEW :) called `myFinalView`

Here's a `myFinalView` with remarks (check this [sqlFiddle with remarks in the VIEW](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06da1/1/0))

Comment: it does not work when i add another time in in another date in the id 36.. pls help me..

Comment: let me try it again.. :)

Comment: Thank you for saving me. Work like a CHARM! can i ask a question? what does the +0000 mean in the time extension?

Comment: How can I create a view out of this sir? How can I chop the sub queries?

Comment: Okay thanks for that.. Can i ask another question?..
How can I add remarks on this? and to leftjoin every remarks input per in/out into one column per day?

Comment: Can u add the remarks in the view sir?                                                  
During the first in I add a remarks "superlate" and then out I add remarks "straight time"
It should appear in the table like
Remarks
superlate, straight time
please help sir.. :/

Comment: can you describe what your remarks table looks like? or is it another column added onto existing table?

Comment: @user3114385, Check out my answer at the bottom it's got a VIEW yeh! created by using VIEW on top of VIEWs

Comment: Thankyou for the view sir.. I just updated the question above for the remarks sir..

Comment: check my answer at the very bottom there's a link to a sqlFiddle with a View that includes remarks

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a `group by` to your query:

```
group by a1.emp_id, date(a1.timestamp), date(a2.timestamp), date(a3.timestamp),
         date(a4.timestamp), date(a5.timestamp), date(a6.timestamp)
```

To be honest, though, I would do the whole query as a conditional aggregation with "in" and "out" on one row.  This would work for one pair, but not three.  I don't understand why you want three pairs on one row.  What about employees that only have two pairs in one day?  Or who have four pairs?

Comment: im working with 3 pairs as the maximum per day. they want it with 3 pairs.. i think they categorized it as morning, afternoon and evening shift? Do you have any idea how to work it on two pairs?

Comment: I just tried your answer sir. now the problem is when the 2nd IN is empty it copies the value of the 1st IN... please heeeelp.. :(

Comment: @user3114385 . . . As I mentioned your query has more issues than just the date issue.